# Returning a function in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I get the following error "TypeError: make_pretty() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)" for the below code snippet. I'm learning python and any help would be helpful...

```
class test:
    def make_pretty(func):
        def inner():
            print("I got decorated")
            func()
        return inner

    def ordinary():
        print("I am ordinary")

pretty1 = test()
pretty = pretty1.make_pretty(pretty1.ordinary)
print(pretty())
```

I also tried it with decorators, but still face the same error..

```
class SmartDivide:
    def smart_divide(self,func):
        def inner(a,b):
            print("I am going to divide",a,"and",b)
            if b == 0:
                print("Whoops! cannot divide")
                return

            return func(a,b)
        return inner

@smart_divide
def divide(self,a,b):
    return a/b

dvd = SmartDivide()
print(dvd.divide(2,5))
dvd.divide(2,0)
```

Comment: Do this without a class. The problem is that methods defined in a class, the first argument will automatically refer to the instance itself. By convention, all methods are defined with `self` as the first argument. This argument is magically passed when using an instance. Before you start using classes, read the following: https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/classes.html Python's class system is actually pretty simple, but a bit different from other common class-based OOP languages like Java.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may need the self keyword

```
class test:
    def make_pretty(self, func):
        def inner():
            print("I got decorated")
            func()
        return inner

    def ordinary(self):
        print("I am ordinary")

pretty1 = test()
pretty = pretty1.make_pretty(pretty1.ordinary)
print(pretty())
```

Comment: thanks..That was very useful...I